# Test saga finally recursion

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I Have next saga function

```
function* fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(() => api.get('/names'));
    yield put(actions.succeeded(response.data));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.failed(e.message));
  } finally {
    yield delay(3000);
    yield put(actions.fetchGraph());
  }
}
```

How I could test `yield put(actions.fetchGraph());` in finally block?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but shouldn't be `iterator().next` after an `iterator.throw` call the result of the `finally` block?

```
const iterator = fetchData()

assert.deepEqual(
  iterator.next().value,
  call(api.get, '/names'),
  "fetchData should yield an Effect call(api.get, '/names')",
)

const error = { message: 'Fake Error' }

// Throw error and test `catch`
assert.deepEqual(
  iterator.throw(error).value,
  put(actions.failed(error.message)),
  "fetchData should yield an Effect put(actions.failed(error.message))",
)

// After `catch` block, `next()` should continue in `finally`
assert.deepEqual(
  iterator.next().value,
  delay(3000),
  "fetchData should yield an Effect delay(3000)",
)
```